# Javascript to add div background image?

Tags: javascript, html, background-image, onmouseover, rollover

I am trying to get a div background image to change when you roll over it as well as change text color. I got the color changing ok, but the bg image isn't. Here's what I got:

In the head:

```
#menu1 {
    background-image: none;
}

<script language="javascript">
function txtroll(x)
{
x.style.color="white";
x.style.background-image="url(images/moragames/logo/moragames_logo_01.png);
}
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<div id="menu1" onmouseover="txtroll(this)" onmouseout="txtout(this)">
```

I cannot seem to get the rollover to add the background image but it changes the font color just fine. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
x.style.backgroundImage="url(images/moragames/logo/moragames_logo_01.png)";
```

instead of -

```
x.style.background-image="url(images/moragames/logo/moragames_logo_01.png)
```

The `style` property of `HTMLElement` has no property called `background-image`.

Answer (score 0):

u can do it with simple css too
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/gfk9E/)

or with Javascript [demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/gfk9E/1/)

**css:**

```
#menu1 {
    background-image: none;
    height:100px;
}
#menu1:hover {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this:

css:

```
.hover {
    background-image: "url(images/moragames/logo/moragames_logo_01.png)";
}
```

js:

```
$('#menu1').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```